# Vector Notation

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, vectors

I just wanna ask, is it wrong if I write vector $v$ as $\bar{v}$ instead of $\textbf{v}$ or $\vec{v}$ in my handwriting? I ask this because someone told me that I was wrong. But, my professor also write vector $v$ as $\bar{v}$ and no one complains, because we know that our context is vector, not line segment or else. Can you guys share your opinion about this?

In my opinion, writing vector $v$ as $\bar{v}$ is just a shorthand notation for handwriting. Is it true?

Comment: a line over a variable has established meaning in other contexts, so it might be good to use different notation. But notation is only notation; if its only for your eyes, then you don't need to care. You might get questions every time you show it to someone else though. Another thing; maybe your lecturer is writing $\overset{\tiny \rightharpoonup}v$ sloppily (this is just a variant of $\vec v$)

Comment: @Shadow From a very rigorous point of view -- that of formal languages -- the question whether one is allowed to use certain characters/symbols in order to denote free variables over which one would like to perform quantification (either existential or universal) ultimately depends exclusively on the set of primary characters/symbols that one allows in the alphabet which lies at the basis of one's formal language. Thus, as long as you pre-declare your primary alphabet to also consist of characters $\bar{v}$ etc, you are entitled to use such characters in mathematical text.

Comment: @Shadow However, as Calvin Khor has pointed out above, such a decision is decidedly uninspired, because at later points in the development of various mathematical theories one would feel the need to introduce secondary symbols, i.e. abbreviations of sorts, that rely on bars/arrows etc, thus leading to a syntactic conflict in interpreting $\bar{v}$ as an *elementary* character of the alphabet or as the secondary (derived) term of the formal language obtained by applying the abbreviation $\bar{\cdot}$ to the elementary character $v$.

Comment: So, actually there is no problem at all if I use $\bar{v}$? I mean as long as the audience understands what I write.

Comment: @Shadow To attempt to give a judicious answer to your question just above, I would like to ask: how do you wish to define the elementary alphabet of your preferred formal language used to express mathematics? Will you allow characters such as $\bar{v}$ or not?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ $\vec{v}$ and $\bar{v}$ or $\vec{}$ and $\bar{}$ could be the same symbol just written differently

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy That is not exactly what my specific question was referring to and it must also be pointed out that you are mistaken in the above statement. At that fundamental level of precisely prescribing the elementary characters which make up (part of) the alphabet of one's formal language, the most minute difference between two characters will very much matter. This is what entitles one to use the elementary letters $x$ and $x'$ as *distinct* letters of an alphabet, thus making it possible to have a quantification such as $(\forall x)(\forall x')P(x, x')$, over *two distinct* variables.

Comment: @ΑΘΩ Symbols aren't characters, they're nonphysical placeholders. Characters have to do with the physical representation of a symbol, but symbols aren't characters.

Comment: @PiKindofGuy While it is true that up to a certain extent the distinctions such as you make could be pertinently made within theories of semiotics, that has nothing much to do with what I meant to say in the above. I am using the term symbol to refer to precisely the concrete, explicit, graphical means of representing names of variables that one would need to specify in one's alphabet, as the primary characters of one's formal language. That there can be a notion of non-material symbols, very much agreed, but that's not part of the discussion at hand here.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Also, to take one more contemplative step in the direction of semiotic theory which you have invited upon this discussion, it is certainly the case that not all symbols are necessarily characters, but any character -- in the usual acceptation of this term in the context of linguistics and graphology -- is a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

I had a professor write their vectors as $\bar{v}$. Of course no one can say that it's *wrong*, it's just notation, what matters is that your audience understands what you write.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Shadow I don't know if it's appropriate to comment a thank you on this site. Click the up arrow to to indicate "This answer is useful" or the down arrow to indicate "This answer is not useful".